# Find people whose name start with a particular letter with sparql Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

This is my query but I don't get any results for records starting with "n"

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q5.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "^(n)").
}
```

Comment: `?itemLabel` isn't bound when the filter is applied because this *label service* is some "magic" fulltext-index applied later. Use the good old `rdfs:label`, i.e. `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q5.
  ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel . FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?itemLabel),  'en'))
  FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "^(n)").
}
limit 10`

Comment: Note, this query will be pretty slow given that a full scan + regex has to be applied.

Comment: thank you it works but is there a faster way to search using substrings

Comment: Not really. Besides `regex`, there are the functions `contains` and `strstarts`, both of which might be slow as well. Without any fullext index - which in fact is triple store dependent - those operations are usually slow given that the whole data has to be processed in the filter. And Wikidata (based on Blazegraph) doesn'T have fulltext index support right now.

Comment: That means, for autocompletion feature, you should build your own fulltext index...

Comment: BTW, names of people usually start with "N", not "n". Try `FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "^N")`, 
`FILTER regex (?itemLabel, "^n", "i")` or `FILTER strstarts (?itemLabel, "N")` (but see AKSW's comments).